# preg_match_all undefined offset notice encountered

Tags: php

I am trying to come up with a general expression which would return the string "logo = ..." for example in this case "logo = Yahoo! logo.svg" but would like it to return the complete string from the "l" in logo until the "|". 
Currently I'm getting and error: Notice: Undefined offset: 0 when clicking submit. Please see script below:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Search</h2>
<form method="post">
Search: <input type="text" name="q" value="Yahoo!"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['q'])) {
$search = $_POST['q'];


$url_2 = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?
action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=$search&rvsection=0&continue=";
$res_2 = file_get_contents($url_2);
$data_2 = json_decode($res_2);

?>

<h2>Search results for '<?php echo $search; ?>'</h2>
<ol>
<?php foreach ($data_2->query->pages as $r): 

?>

<li>

<?php foreach($r->revisions[0] as $a); 
echo $a; 

print_r(preg_match_all('/ logo += (.*)/', $a, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER));
echo trim($result[0][0]); 
?>

</li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ol>

<?php 
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r(preg_match_all('/ logo += (.*)/', $a, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER));
echo trim($result[0][0]);
```

There are two errors in this sample of code. First there is a space before "logo" in the pattern. Your test string doesn't seem to have this space.

Second, when you use `preg_match` or `preg_match_all` and want to use the match result, you need to use an if statement (because if the pattern is not found, indexes of `$result` are not set):

```
if (preg_match_all('/logo += (.*)/', $a, $result)) {
    echo trim($result[0][0]);
} else {
    echo 'Not found';
}
```

Note too that `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` is the default value of the 4th parameter of `preg_match_all`